# PHP counting uppercase letters (not working)

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and trying to count all the uppercase letters in the text area, thought I am not able get anything when I hit the 'submit' button. Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 function caps($s) {
   $u = 0;
   $d = 0;
   $n = strlen($s);

   for ($x=0; $x<$n; $x++) {
       $d = ord($s[$x]);
       if ($d > 64 && $d < 91) {
           $u++;
       }
   } 

   return $u;
   }
  $n1=$_POST['n1'];
     echo 'caps: ' .  caps($n1) . "\n";
}
?>
  <form><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="n1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['n1'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['n1']);}?>"></textarea>
 <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: There must be a `<form></form>` in order to submit. Enclose your submit button and text area in a form

Comment: Thanks I got the button working still I didnt get the required output

Comment: text are should also come into the form tags

Comment: Ok thanks I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the form **method** to post your code should be something like:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 function caps($s) {
   $u = 0;
   $d = 0;
   $n = strlen($s);

   for ($x=0; $x<$n; $x++) {
       $d = ord($s[$x]);
       if ($d > 64 && $d < 91) {
           $u++;
       }
   } 

   return $u;
   }
  $n1=$_POST['n1'];
     echo 'caps: ' .  caps($n1) . "\n";
}
?>
  <form method="post"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="n1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['n1'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['n1']);}?>"></textarea>
 <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Make sure you set the form method to **post**.
If you don't provide method the form uses get method instead of post.

Answer (score 1):

This example will help you.

```
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]$/", $s, $matches);
$all_upper_cases = count($matches);
```

Comment: Its about the textbox I am facing issue with not the function

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function count_capitals($s) {
  return strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $s));
}
```

ex.

```
 $n1=$_POST['n1'];
 echo 'caps: ' .  count_capitals($n1) . "\n";
```

textbox:

```
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="n1" value="<?php count_capitals($n1) ?>"></textarea>
```

Comment: Nothings showing up , I just put the function in if statement and replaced the textarea . and ex.